# Difference between この and こんな

Tags: grammar

Can someone help me with the difference between この and こんな and when to use each?

Also I see that こんな is almost always with に particle, why's that?

Does the rules to when to use each of those apply to the difference between その and そんな as well?

Comment: この = this, こんな = this kind of (short for このような)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

この translates to "this" in English in the sense that you're talking about このペン/this pen, この犬/this dog, etc.

こんな means "such" or "this kind/type of" or "like this". [Jisho has plenty of examples for this](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%20%23sentences):

> こんな男は信頼できない。
>
> Such a man cannot be relied upon.

こんなに means "so" or "to this degree". [There are plenty of examples for this as well](http://jisho.org/search/%E3%81%93%E3%82%93%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AB%20%23sentences):

> 彼がこんなに遅いのは変だ。
>
> It is odd that he is so late.

Comment: Any insight about the に particle? I'm sued to see it used to idicate movement or indirect object so it makes not much sense it after こんな

Comment: @FelipeOliveira the に particle is used for all sorts of things, in this case it changes the meaning of こんな in the manner illustrated above. Don't try to read too much into it, particles are very versatile.

Comment: Bit late to the post but it seems that the に takes the adjectival noun こんな and turns it into an adverb. Much like other adjectival nouns, such as 静かな, can be turned into adverbs, 静かに. The only difference is that the な doesn't get dropped. Just thought I'd add my opinion for future viewers. I didn't realize this until now.